# Microsoft or other sources of guidelines for naming SQL objects

Tags: sql-server, naming

where can i find Microsoft or any other best practices and naming conventions for SQL server?

Comment: there are a few tools to audit SQL like a FxCop type review.

Comment: Do what feels right to you, makes sense for the project and leaves you with a feeling that if someone new were to come into your schema, they would be able to (rather) quickly figure out your schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official microsoft documentation for best practices for sql naming conventions  and that is the reason you find so many conventions for sql. Pick one convention and make sure its followed in your project. Here's an [example](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dev/sql_best_practices_p1.aspx)